# How to create a custom post while submitting the form

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like to create a custom post when my form is submitted and insert form data into that custom post.

When I searched I found a suggestion to use "Gravity forms and gravity forms+custom post type". But I need my own solution.

This is my code:

```
$title= $_POST['your_name'];
 $decription=$_POST['e_mail'];
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
  'post_content'  => $decription,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post type'     => 'EmpResume'
  //'post_author'   => 1,
  //'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

But it stored my form data in "wp_posts" table rather in my custom post.

Comment: IMHO, go with the plugin solution. If you do not know how to do this without a plugin, it is better to use a plugin or pay a developer to code it for you. This is just too big project to handle here, and most probably no one is going to code this for free

Comment: I tried to install gravity form plugin but I could not install it. If u know any other plugin which will do this pls inform

Comment: [Front-end form save post tutorial for Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic can you tell me clearly what to do ? I have created custom fields using ACF only.

Comment: Custom post types are always stored in the `posts` table. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Which plugin you're using for the contact form? It looks likeyou're thinking about  **Gravity forms**. You can create it with a custom function when the action `gform_after_submission` is fired - https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/

For Contact form 7, there is another hook, see here:  wpcf7_before_send_mail, wpcf7_mail_sent
http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.3/

Ninjaforms...http://hookr.io/plugins/ninja-forms/2.9.28/#index=a
for the other plugins you should have a look yourself.

If it's too complicated, go for plugin solution. I have found this one for Gravity forms but haven't tried it personally. https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/

Comment: "gform_after_submission" this function can be used only if you have its plugin right? But i cannot use as i do not have it. i tried but i cannot download the "gravity form" plugin. any link to download will be helpful

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's missundersunding from my site. You have to buy a licence. However, this kind of action/hook is supported in many other contact forms, which are free. I have updated the answer.